# Retrieve files from iOS app Documents folder via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line

For the project I work on, we have to set up performance metrics. The way we do it is that the simulator writes CSV files to a known location. We then retrieve theses files and make graphs out of it. Piece of cake.

We also have these tests running on the device. In that case, the files are created in the Documents directory.

While I can retrieve these files via the organizer, I'd be much more interested in automating that.

**How can I retrieve files from an iPhone app via the command line rather than the organizer?**

Answer (score 3):

You can actually access the content of your app from your computer, using https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy (originally https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) .
It's as simple as :

./ios-deploy --download=/Documents --bundle_id com.mycompany.myapp -2 dest_dir

You can do much more, like listing the content of the app, debug using lldb etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iFuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/wiki), as part of [libimobiledevice](https://www.libimobiledevice.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the documents folder on your iOS device from your computer without itunes.
I run an webserver within my app so i can download the files via http. For zero configuration setup i use Apples Bonjour.

look here:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/